# VS Code: I can Git Clone in VS Code terminal (Bash) using SSH but get permission denied (public key) in VS Code Source Control

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, ssh, git-clone, vscode-remote-ssh

I really need some help here.  I am stuck trying to use the Source Control option in VS Code to clone a few git repositories.  I can successfully clone them onto my C: drive via the bash terminal in VS Code using SSH without any issues. I run the following:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add C:/my/file/path/private_key
ssh-add -l
ssh-T git@github.com
git clone git@github.com/the_repository
```

All of these commands work, with the expected results. Sure enough, I get the repositories in the target location.  Can also Git Push.  No issues at all.

However, when I try to git clone the exact same repositions using the VS Code UI option select "Source Code" > "Open Folder" > "Provide repo URL" > navigate to the folder in my C: Drive as the target location, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote directory
```

I have tried EVERYTHING. Help from colleagues, ChatGPT walkthrough, other Stack Overflow tickets, etc. I know my key pairs are working since I can clone via the VSCode terminal but cannot figure out why I can't do the same with using the VS Code UI. I tried updating my config file, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have all of the required extensions (remote-ssh, etc.). I am convinced it has something to do with my VS Code configuration on my local machine but can't figure it out.

Anyone else come across this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the bash terminal is using the `[bash_home]/.ssh` folder and VS Code is using `C:\Users\your.username\.ssh`

Add the same `.ssh` folder and files in `C:\Users\your.username\.ssh`

Comment: Thanks a lot @vinnyjames!  I ran `echo ~` in my bash terminal, and it was pointing to my H: drive. I copied all of the contents in my /.ssh folder in my C: drive and tried it again, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks again!